# Quarkus MySQL JDBC Dependency

Tags: java, mysql, quarkus

````
It added MySQL dependency, but gives error.<br><br>
mvn quarkus:add-extension -Dextensions="io.quarkus:quarkus-jdbc-mysql"

✅ Adding dependency io.quarkus:quarkus-jdbc-mysql:jar

    <dependency>
          <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
          <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-mysql</artifactId>
    </dependency>

```
[ERROR]   The project org.acme:agroal-datasources:1.0-SNAPSHOT (/path/java/quarkus/agroal-datasource-2/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.quarkus:quarkus-jdbc-mysql:jar is missing. @ line 50, column 17
```
````

Comment: [This GitHub page](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/2323) might be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Adding version worked:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-mysql</artifactId>
      <version>0.23.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

So the problem is that the quarkus:add-extension didn't add the version: `0.23.2`

Comment: Actually, I think this works as designed. I have defined the version of quarkus only for the `quarkus-bom` artifact. I created the `pom` from the examples/docs of quarkus directly